# Changing background color in Android SDK by clicking a button does not work

Tags: android, sdk, colors, background

I have a simple program which is able to change the background color after clicking a button, but it does not work

```
public class ChangeBackgroundActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
    Button blueButton;
    LinearLayout myLO;
    @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        myLO=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.layout.main);
        blueButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        blueButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            myLO.setBackgroundColor(0x0000FF); //blue color code #0000FF    
        }
    });
    }
}
```

Comment: Does't work means you didn't get any color or are you getting a transparent background? try using myLO.setBackgroundColor(0xFF0000FF);

Comment: You are made mistake in this line myLO = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.layout.main);. See my post below

Comment: use R.id.main and not R.layout.main, don't forget to mark he answer as accepted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try With this,

**main.xml**

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/myLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="64dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="71dp"
            android:text="changeColor" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

**ChangeBackgroundActivity.java**

```
public class ChangeBackgroundActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
    Button blueButton;
    LinearLayout myLO;
    @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        myLO=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
        blueButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        blueButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            myLO.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

        }
    });
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you made changes on OP solution?

Comment: @K_Anas: I can't get you what you are telling OP solution means

Comment: @DavidNg:     Sorry for the inconvenience, in the previous post the entire layout wasn't shown, now i edited my code. it works fine. You can use it

Comment: @DavidNg It's your LinearLayout Id. You are making mistake on this one. you wish to make changes in layout means, you won't give the layout.

Comment: @K_Anas: I'm really sorry, by mistakenly it happend

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted yours, your answer is completely wrong and i haven't downvoted it

Comment: @K_Anas: I can't get your point. What is wrong in my answer. I run this code it works fine, and one more thing, i gave up vote for your answer,at the time of voting little bit hang in my my system it may be my cursor hold on down button, i verified once you send the notification

Comment: @K_Anas: i got my error point and thanks...:) and edited my answer... once again thanks and Sorry for downvoting

Comment: glad you get it now ;), that's why i asked you have copy/paste the op is question!! the error is not the color!! OP means asker

Comment: can you guys vote my question? I am now not have enough point to vote you guys

Answer (score 3):

use

```
myLO=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main);
```

insteadof

```
myLO=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.layout.main);
```

your layout must be like that

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/main"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an xml file(selector file) and put it in drawable folder in res(res->drawable->yourselectorfile.xml. After that set xml file in button's background in your layout file

**button_background_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/your_hover_image" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/your_hover_image" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/your_hover_image"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/your_simple_image" />
</selector>
```

Now set the above file in button's background.

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/grey_text"
    android:background="@drawable/button_background_selector"/>
```

and for changing color use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_pressed="true"
           android:color="#000000" /> <!-- pressed -->
     <item android:state_focused="true"
           android:color="#000000" /> <!-- focused -->
     <item android:color="#FFFFFF" /> <!-- default -->
 </selector>
```

as your button_background_selector.xml

Answer (score 0):

Use this, this worked for me:

```
YourView.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255));
```